# Derivative of $f(3x+1,3x-1)=4$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

This exercise asks me to take the derivative of

$$f(3x+1,3x-1)=4$$

where this equality is said to be valid for all $x$.
The exercise specifically asks me to prove that

$$\frac{∂}{∂x}f(3x+1,3x-1)=-\frac{∂}{∂x}f(3x+1,3x-1)$$

The first thing I though was to apply the partial derivative operator to the both sides of the function:

$$\frac{∂}{∂x}f(3x+1,3x-1)=\frac{∂}{∂x}4 \implies \frac{∂}{∂x}f(3x+1,3x-1) = 0 \implies \\ \frac{∂}{∂x}f(3x+1,3x-1) = - \frac{∂}{∂x}f(3x+1,3x-1)$$

but the exercise uses the chain rule, so I'm assuming that this can't be made. Could someone clarify for me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hint: Write $f(a,b)$ so that $f$ is function of the variables $a$ and $b$.  Then, use $a=3x+1$ and $b=3x-1$.  Then, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ can be written in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know how to solve in this way, but I need to know what's wrong with the way I did

Comment: Since you can consider $f$ as a function of $x$, you could look at $\frac{d}{dx}$ of both sides (not the partial derivative).  Since the derivative is always zero, the derivatives are equal.  So, in that sense, your work is correct.  The use of partial derivatives in the expected answer is somewhat disconcerting because the function is a univariate function, and I wonder if the problem has a typo and is asking a different question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I don't see why you say we cannot take the partial derivative, and in fact I would say that you must, because $f(3x+1,3x-1)$ is a variable depending on $x$ and we only want the partial derivative with respect to $x$ since we do not know how $x$ changes over the whole unspecified parameter space.

Comment: @user21820 You could write $g(x)=f(3x+1,3x-1)$ to see that $g$ is a function of one variable.  Even though $f$ is a function of two variables, the values across $f$'s domain don't matter because its value depends only on the single value $x$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: As I said in my previous comment, you do not know how $x$ changes over the parameter space, so you cannot take the direct derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open; let $\varphi: x \mapsto (3x+1, 3x-1)$ on $I$; let $f\circ \varphi (x) = 4$ on $I$; and let
$g: x \mapsto \varphi(x) \mapsto f\circ \varphi(x) = 4$ on $I$. Then
$g'(x) = 0 = \big( D_{1}f(3x+1,3x-1), D_{2}f(3x+1, 3x-1) \big) \cdot (3,3)$ on $I$,
so
$$
D_{1}f(3x+1, 3x-1) = -D_{2}f(3x+1, 3x-1)
$$
on $I$.

Comment: If you're assuming there is a mistake in the question, you should say so. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is certainly **not** $\partial_1$!

Comment: A clear composition takes place; not sure what you are talking about,man.

Comment: You use $D_1$ and $D_2$, but the question is not about differentiating with respect to the first or second input but about differentiating with respect to $x$.

Comment: @user21820: Please make sure you understand something before ejecting any opinions. I will explain this to you. $D_{1}f(3x+1, 3x-1)$ means we first differentiate $f$ with respect to the first argument and then get $D_{1}f$ and then put $(3x+1,3x-1)$ in. Understand? Have you ever heard of composition and the relevant derivative theory?

Comment: @user21820: In short, $D_{1}f$ is a NEW function.

Comment: @Chou Way to go!  I believe that you and I are in alignment!

Comment: I *know* that, but look at the question! It asks to prove $E = -E$ for some expression $E$. Not the one you have in your answer's conclusion! I never said your working is incorrect, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: And please don't assume I don't know the notation or the mathematics. It is a completely wrong assumption. $D_1, D_2$ are simply **different** higher-order functions from $D_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ that the asker has in his question!

Comment: @user21820 (i) Give a "satisfactory"answer you want to see; and (ii) One can say only that much under chain rule.

Comment: (i) I didn't because it was already answered by Michael Burr's second comment in which he also suggests that there may be a typo. (ii) Well whether or not the asker's working is correct actually depends on the actual formal definition of partial derivatives. In a certain framework it indeed is correct but just silly. (*) Briefly, in a proper formal framework we treat $f$ as a function, not a dependent variable. Then $f(\cdots)$ would be a variable. If $x$ is an independent variable, then regardless of any other independent variables $D_x f(\cdots) = D_x (4) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we have a function $f$ of two variables, say $s$ and $t$, and in turn $s$ and $t$ are functions of a single variable $x$.  That is we have $f(s,t)$ and $s=3x+1$ and $t=3x-1$.

So, we introduce a new function, $g(x)=f(s(x),t(x))=f(3x+1,3x-1)$.  We are given that $g(x)=4$ for all $x$.  And this implies that $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$.  So, from the chain-rule, we have

$$\begin{align}
g'(x)&=\left.\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=3x+1,t=3x-1}\frac{ds}{dx}+\left.\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial t}\right|_{s=3x+1,t=3x-1}\frac{dt}{dx}\\\\
&=3\left.\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=3x+1,t=3x-1}+3\left.\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial t}\right|_{s=3x+1,t=3x-1}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

from which we see

$$\left.\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial s}\right|_{s=3x+1,t=3x-1}=-\left.\frac{\partial f(s,t)}{\partial t}\right|_{s=3x+1,t=3x-1}$$

Comment: If you're assuming there is a mistake in the question, you should say so. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is certainly **not** $\partial_1$!

Comment: @user21820 I don't know precisely what you mean.  Please tell me more.  This post was just a sincere attempt at illustrating a way forward.  Does that make better sense now?

Comment: yes, but couldn't I just proceed as I thought in the first way?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Well, the way the equations are written it would imply $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$.  But this is not the case.

Comment: But I would have: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$,  $-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0 = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Exactly.  But that is not true in general.  We have here instead is $$f_1(3x+1,3x-1)=-f_2(3x+1,3x-1)$$where the subscript indicates a partial derivative with respect to the first or second variable.  Make sense??

Comment: @Dr.MV could you update your answer with this in a more clear way? Sorry, I can't understand.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I really would like to give you the best answer I can.  If you would outline where the sticking points of my answer are, I am happy to try to improve the answer.  For now, it is almost 1am and I need rest as I have chemotherapy tomorrow.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have written but it has nothing to do with the question. If you read the question it explicitly asks to prove that $E = -E$ where $E$ is some expression. So if you think the question has some typo, then yes your answer may be relevant, but as it stands the question is not about the partial derivatives with respect to the two inputs.

Comment: By the way, all the best for your chemotherapy and hope you get better.